# What genre is "The Mysteries"?

Tags: genre, bill-watterson, john-kascht, the-mysteries

I recently finished reading *The Mysteries* and was somewhat confused about which genre it should be classified under. It doesn't seem like it's exactly a short story (because the illustrations seem to be part of the story), but it's not exactly a graphic novel either. I'm not sure exactly how to categorize this. Can someone explain what genre this book falls under?

Comment: If you liked *The Mysteries*, then it transcends genre. If you didn't like *The Mysteries*, then it's a muddle that can't decide which genre it wants to belong to.

Comment: [Meta consensus](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/424/17) is that "what genre is this" questions should be closed. (Personally I've always disagreed with that, but I'm almost the only downvoter on those meta answers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is described as a fable for adults and so with its plot of Kingdom experiencing calamities and the kings despatch of his knights in search of cause and perhaps remedy it is representitive of the fantasy fiction 'genre' in the graphic novel 'format'. As you point out the pictures form part of narrative aspect and this is a feature of graphic novels.
I suspect your question re pigeonholing arises by virtue of its format.